Unassign entries with unsatisfied hard constraints (Timefold ai Over-constraint planning)
I am currently learning timefold ai with the given examples(Spring Boot). You can find the code base with this repository. I wrote a new constraint as follows:
public class TimetableConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                // other constraints
                ...

                // custom constraint
                ninthGradeStudentsDislikesMaths(constraintFactory),
        };
    }


    Constraint ninthGradeStudentsDislikesMaths(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        // 9th grade students does not like Maths

        return constraintFactory.forEach(Lesson.class)
                .filter(lesson -> lesson.getStudentGroup().equals("9th grade") && 
                        lesson.getSubject().equals("Math"))
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("9th grade students does not like Maths");
    }
}

I want to ignore/unassign the lessons if they do not satisfy this constraint. But, by default timefold assigns all the entries. This is the documentation related to over-constraint planning. It is not clear for me. If anyone has done this before, please help.
Thanks in advance!
I tried using the official documentation from timefold about Overconstrained planning.
@PlanningVariable(allowsUnassigned = true)
private Timeslot timeslot;

@PlanningVariable(allowsUnassigned = true)
private Room room;

Then change score type to:
@PlanningScore
private HardMediumSoftScore score;

Final score I got was 0hard/-2medium/0soft
But when i did that, no entries were assigned.

Please be specific on what "didn't work" for you. What have you tried? What were the results? What made you conclude "it" didn't work?

When i did like that, all the lessons were unassigned.

Specifying constraints doesn't mean that something will happen. It is not an order that is guaranteed to be fulfilled. Instead, it is a guideline to the solver which solutions to prefer over others.
If your constraints say that certain lessons should remain unassigned, the solver will try to do that. But if it finds better solutions where the lessons are assigned, it will pick that solution instead. So this boils down to your constraints, and how you decided to penalize/reward the individual situations.
If it looks like the solver is ignoring the constraint with unassigned lessons, either make the constraint harder (move to a higher score level) or increase its weight. Both will make it more important than other constraints, and will make the solver treat it as such.
Balancing constraints between each other could be seen as either art or dark magic. You should experiment with your constraint and match weights until the solver starts giving you the solutions you desire.
But you also need to remember about score traps. Sometimes the solver cannot find some solutions, because there are no roads leading there (requiring custom moves), or because those solutions have the exact same score as others better ones.
